# How to change displayed value from many2one field in OpenERP (Odoo)?

Tags: python, odoo

I'm creating a new module on Odoo (OpenERP) but I can't use a field correctly.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKQpT.png)

I can select a field from another class (defined in the same module) but i need to change the value displayed.

In the example I have the string "menu,2", for the field **piatto**. This string is obtained from the class **ordini**, with a *many2one* field, but i want to display the field named **nome** (showed in the following image).

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQwRL.png)

This is the python file.

```
class menu(osv.Model):
_name = "menu"
_description = "Menu"
_order = "tipo"
_columns = {
    'nome': fields.char('Nome', size=80, required=True),
    'tipo': fields.selection([
                ('antipasto', 'antipasto'),
                ('primo', 'primo piatto'),
                ('secondo', 'secondo piatto'),
                ('contorno', 'contorno'),
                ('dolce', 'dolce')
                ], 'Tipo di piatto'),
    'prezzo': fields.float('Prezzo', digits=(10,2), required=True),
    'ingredienti': fields.text('Lista ingredienti'),
    'immagine': fields.binary('Immagine'),
}
_sql_constraints = [('unique_name', 'unique(nome)', 'Il piatto è già presente.')]

class ordini(osv.Model):
_name = "ordini"
_description = "Ordini"
_columns = {
    'dipendente': fields.many2one('hr.employee', 'Dipendente', ondelete='set null', required=True),
    'dettagli_ids': fields.one2many('ordini.dettagli', 'n_ordine', 'Ordine'), 
}

class ordini_dettagli(osv.Model):        
_name = "ordini.dettagli"
_description = "Dettagli ordine"
_columns = {
    'n_ordine': fields.integer('Ordine', readonly=True),
    'piatto': fields.many2one('menu', 'Piatto'),
    'qta': fields.integer('Quantità'),
    'prezzo_piatto': fields.related('piatto','prezzo',type='float',string='Prezzo',readonly=True),
}
_defaults = {
     'qta': 1,
}
```

EDIT
I also need to update the field **prezzo** when i select the **piatto** entry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare which field is used for the object name, using the [`_rec_name` attribute](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model._rec_name). In your case:

```
class menu(osv.Model):
    _name = "menu"
    _description = "Menu"
    _order = "tipo"
    _rec_name = 'nome'

    # ...
```

Alternatively, you could just rename `nome` to `name`, since `name` is the default value for `_rec_name`.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine.
I've added another request in the post, if you can help me again. ;)

Comment: You could also overwrite name_get and make use of the context so it displays a particular value for your form but the default value on other forms if you wanted this.  However, if you are starting to use name_get or _rec_name, you should always consider overriding name_get and name_search as well.

Comment: @AdrianMerrall `"if you are starting to use name_get or _rec_name, you should always consider overriding name_get and name_search as well"`. Why do you say so? I understand why changing `name_get` should in most cases also imply changing `name_search` accordingly. But the default implementation of both those methods already use `_rec_name`, so if you just change the value of this property without changing anything else, I think you should be good.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer Well spotted - quite right.  If you are only setting _rec_name you will be fine with the default name_search, just if you override name_get you may need to do name_search.